# AOSP FileObserver does not notify System Service

Tags: android, android-source

I added a new System Service to the AOSP code, the goal is to monitor access to files in the user's whole "/storage" directory. The android system is compiling and the System Service has started correctly, I verified it with the Slog messages.

However, if something happens under the /storage directory, the UserFileAccessObserver does not get notified. I even used adb shell to create random files under /storage but nothing happened...

Why is it not working? Does this custom service needs to request access permissions to the external storage? I am stuck here for quite some time now.

Thanks! Here is the class code.

```
public class FileGuardService extends SystemService {
    private static final String TAG = "FileGuardService";

    static final String SERVICE = "fileguard";

    private UserFileAccessObserver mUserFileAccessObserver;

    public FileGuardService(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Slog.d(TAG, "File Guard Service instance created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Slog.d(TAG, "File Guard Service started");
        mUserFileAccessObserver = new UserFileAccessObserver();
        mUserFileAccessObserver.startWatching();
    }

    private static class UserFileAccessObserver extends FileObserver {
        public UserFileAccessObserver() {
            super( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS);
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            Slog.d(TAG, "Received an event!");
            Slog.d(TAG, "Event received, event id is " + event + " and the file path is " + path);
        }
    }
}
```

I even checked other System Services to check if they were getting notified and they are, however, none of them is monitoring the /storage directory.